# Are float based layouts still needed with modern browsers?

Tags: css, html, layout, css-float

Once apon a time IE6 lacked support for CSS features such as "display: table-cell" and inline-block, resulting in "float" being hijacked and used for layout - which is was never designed for (or particularly good at).

Using floats seems to result in overly fragile layouts that are difficult to maintain and often break completely with changing dynamic content.

This was a necessary evil in its day, however now that support for browsers pre-IE8 are less of a concern, we should in theory be able to move away from floats and use the parts of CSS that actually work well for layouts - such as the aforementioned display: table-cell and inline-block.

I'm currently considering of recommending my team move away from float based designs entirely - am I at risk of painting myself into a corner and having problems down the line , or is this a better option if older browser support is not important on our project?

Comment: I'm not sure `float` has a replacement in CSS, how you could build this layout without using float? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRcff/).

Comment: [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/3WUx3/), though it behaves a bit differently at low resolutions ;)

Comment: I'm not suggesting float isn't still used in some scenarios - it still has a use-case, the above is one such example.

However if it weren't for the spacer in the middle, this would be quite simply with display: table-cell. Which would satisfy most grid based layouts quite fine.

Comment: @jmeas `position: absolute` is not a way to do that, what about HTML after your divs? check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRcff/9/).

Comment: Float is not created for layouts... It is for positioning images in text... You can always ignore float if you know about `position` and `display` http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/03/14/cross-browser-web-design/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Should you move away from floats entirely?

Sure, so long as you don't need the deeper browser support. When it comes down to it, what *really* matters is whether the page displays properly for the largest numbers of visitors to your site as possible, right?

Another issue that should be of concern to you is maintainability, but I can't say that it'd be accurate to say that either method is less maintainable than the other *in every situation*. So I'd just ask yourself what layout method your team is more familiar with and how far back you need to support.

`display: table-cell` is supported in IE8+. Float displays can go all the way back to IE6.

#### Other thoughts & the future...

Contrary to what you said about floats, I think when used right they can be very predictable. My primary qualm with them is the need to clear the parent which is a bit awkward. Further, popular scaffolding systems like [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) and [960-Grid](http://960.gs/) still choose to use floats, and for good reason: they're useful, have great cross-browser support, and can do what you need to do.

With that said, the future is looking good for Css and layouts. There are two upcoming models of layout in Css: the [grid system](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-grid/#grid-declaration0) and the [flexbox model](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#flex-containers). Neither are recommendations yet, so [browser support is a bit shaky on them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility).

The grid system is similar to `display: table-cell` but gives you much greater control. Flexbox tries to generalize and abstract the idea of displaying elements, which allows for really powerful, fluid (or 'flexible') layouts. Both of these will be pretty amazing once they're implemented in browsers.

If you want to read more on usage of flexbox, I [recommend the excellent MDN article about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

Were I you, I'd just hold out and use floats – in particular, by using a scaffolding framework. I haven't worried about writing scaffolding Css in a long, long time; I use frameworks since the code is already written for me. And, for me, I'd only find it worthwhile to completely restructure a project once flexbox and the grid system are a recommendation and more widely implemented.

Comment: Thanks, this sums things up pretty well. In our case our UI is complex enough (and user configurable enough) that float based layouts just don't seem to cut it, where table-cell seems much more stable.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said is about what is best for your team, but believe me... if you use `float` correct and in the right places you don't get a layout breaking because you change the div content.

But in the future the best way will be using [flexbox](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/), you can accomplish everything about blocks horizontal, vertical, with same sizes, diferrent sizes... Anyway when all browsers support it, will be aewsome.